# Angular CORS works for GET but not for DELETE

Tags: java, angularjs, glassfish, jax-rs, cors

I have an Angular application making a call cross origin. All of the GET calls work great. The DELETE calls, however throw the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my.url.com:8080/api/invoices/12768. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

On the backend I am using JAX-RS with Glassfish 4.1 and Java 8. I am creating the ResponseBuilder like so:

```
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response
                    .status(status)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE")
                    .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                    .allow("OPTIONS");
```

In Angular I am making the service call like so:

```
$http.delete(requestUrl)
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
```

The thing is, this works perfectly well:

```
$http.get(requestUrl)
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
```

Any idea why GET's would be working, but not DELETE?

Edit:

As another note, I know it isn't the server side, because if I run the delete call through [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) on my local computer the DELETE works perfectly.

Edit 2:

**Request headers**

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/{ipaddress} Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:applications
```

**Response headers**

```
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1209600
Allow: OPTIONS 
Content-Type: application/json 
Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 23:39:10 GMT
```

Content-Length: 0

These are the headers from the working Advanced Rest Client

Comment: What browser are you running this on?

Comment: HTTP details from request and response please.

Comment: Chrome. What do you mean by "HTTP details from request and response please."?

Comment: request/response from network in chrome or where ever you're sending it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently Angular strips content-type from the header. Using this works:

```
$http.delete({url:request,headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
```